# Error in resource folder - Android / Eclipse

Tags: android, resources

I have no idea why this behaviour is occuring, but I'll try and explain...

I would like to have a different image used in an application for a normal hdpi device, as I would for a large screen ('large' by android standards is over 5" I believe) hpdi device.

As of such, I created this folder structure

```
res 
  -->
    drawable-hdpi
    drawable-hdpi-large
```

.. And it was all good, no errors, things seemed fine. So I added my first image to the hdpi folder as per this:

```
res 
  -->
    drawable-hdpi
                -->
                  image.png

    drawable-hdpi-large
```

... And everything was fine, good. So I added my alternative image to the large hdpi folder like this:

```
res 
  -->
    drawable-hdpi
                -->
                  image.png

    drawable-hdpi-large // Error 'cross icon' appear on this folder.
                -->
                  image.png
```

... And it breaks. There is no error text in any of the console out puts. Validate doesn't come up with any errors. Nothing. Just stops compiling the R class as per other resource errors.

So why does this happen? I've used folders for localisation before, with a layout and layout-large folder for the large devices to use and I didn't get this. Is there something special about drawable localisation, that isn't mentioned in the docs?

I've lost track of just how many bugs, in-consistencies and just plain annoyances I've found with android. Really is trying my patience!

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated! :)

Andy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, the folder resource identifiers were in the wrong order

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

My new folder should have been drawable-large-hdpi.

*Sigh*

Andy.

Comment: Haha. Annoying, but at least it was an easy fix. :)

Comment: Yeah, just a bit frustrating that there was no error message. Would have been a lot easier if there was! :)